# Loop between 2 csv files stops at first mach

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, for-loop

I have 2 `csv` files: the source file has only one column with IDs (one ID per line). The 2nd `csv` file has the IDs plus extra info. I would like to check each ID from `file1` against all the records in `file2` and if there is a match, to print out the row that matched (from `file1`) with the corresponding info from `file2`.

The files look like this.

Source:

```
0234906006000
0234765306000
0231316005000
0234906006000
0212134006000
0125667806000
3334906006000
1778986006000
0239906006000
```

Mine:

```
02349-34-010-000,Adam
05125-07-033-000,Michael
05172-04-042-000,Debora
8071-33-001-000,Matt
2349-38-007, 2349-38-011, 2349-38-012,Ken
0234906006000,Roger
3334906006000,Hummels
0231316005000,Don
0501401028000,Gregg
```

My code looks like:

```
import csv
source = csv.reader(open("denver_source.csv"))
mine = csv.reader(open("denver_mine.csv"))
output = {}
for line in source:
    print(line[0])
    for xline in mine:
        if line[0] not in xline: continue
        output[line[0]] = xline
    print(xline)
print("Result", output)
```

I get a result but I do not get all the matches, only the first match:

```
0234906006000
['0501401028000', 'Gregg']
0234765306000
['0501401028000', 'Gregg']
0231316005000
['0501401028000', 'Gregg']
0234906006000
['0501401028000', 'Gregg']
0212134006000
['0501401028000', 'Gregg']
0125667806000
['0501401028000', 'Gregg']
3334906006000
['0501401028000', 'Gregg']
1778986006000
['0501401028000', 'Gregg']
0239906006000
['0501401028000', 'Gregg']
Result: {'0234906006000': ['0234906006000', 'Roger']}
```

Can you please help me understand where I fail in continuing the loop  properly in the second file? I apologize if this was posted before but I only found more complex examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after you iterate through the second `.csv` in your inner loop you reach the end and no new lines can be read again.

You should be using something like this where the second file is going to `seek(0)` to go back to the beginning after the inner loop breaks. Also, it is advisable to use `with` statements to open files since they make sure the file is closed when its body has executed:

```
with open("denver_source.csv") as cf1, open("denver_mine.csv") as cf2:
    source = csv.reader(cf1)
    mine = csv.reader(cf2)
    for line in source:
        for xline in mine:
             if line[0] in xline: 
                 output[line[0]] = xline
                 break
        cf2.seek(0)
```

The noteworthy thing here is that you call `seek(0)` on the file you supply to `csv.reader` and not the instance of `csv.reader`. That is, you call `cf2.seek(0)` and not `mine.seek(0)`; the changes will be reflected on the `reader` instance and you'll be able to re-iterate as needed.

Of course, you could re-factor this to use the `with` for every iteration of `line in source` instead of `seek(0)`; that's really down to personal preference.

Comment: thank you for the input. I will try now although I know I tried before and it said that csv.reader object does not have the seek attribute

Comment: @Robert got confused, you seek the original file (here `cf2`) you opened and the changes are reflected in the `csv.reader` object you create from that file object.

Comment: thank you Jim. I understand now. I modified your version to account for list[0] as it needs a string, not a list item. Now it works well. The lines modified were: `if line[0] in xline:
    output[line[0]] = xline
    break`

Comment: @Robert I'll add that to the answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're specifically referring to line[0]. That's why it's only giving you the first match. Your loop is going X amount of times (x being how many lines are in the csv), but still checking to see if line[0] is in `mine`every loop iteration.

Try this:

```
import csv
source = csv.reader(open("denver_source.csv"))
mine = csv.reader(open("denver_mine.csv"))
output = {}
for line in source:
    print(line)
    for xline in mine:
        if line not in xline: continue
        output[line] = xline
    print(xline)
print("Result", output)
```

Comment: Using your version I get a different result, but still not ok. I wrote line[0] to be able and compare the string, not the list item.
The first loop goes well, but the second one fails. Through the first loop it goes every time but over the nested loop it goes only for the first item in file1.

Comment: What did my result give you. I didn't compile it, it was just the first thing I noticed. If you tell me what it gave you I can assist further.

Comment: sure. The output is empty. the results look like this. Hope it formats ok in the comment

    ['0234906006000']
    ['0501401028000', 'Gregg']
    ['0234765306000']
    ['0501401028000', 'Gregg']
    ['0231316005000']
    ['0501401028000', 'Gregg']
    ['0234906006000']
    ['0501401028000', 'Gregg']
    ['0212134006000']
    ['0501401028000', 'Gregg']
    ['0125667806000']
    ['0501401028000', 'Gregg']
    ['3334906006000']
    ['0501401028000', 'Gregg']
    ['1778986006000']
    ['0501401028000', 'Gregg']
    ['0239906006000']
    ['0501401028000', 'Gregg']
    Result {}

Comment: I think my error is when going through the second loop, with xline because I always get the 'Gregg row' in the print (last row in the file).

Comment: I'll take a look at it. Can you include examples of each csv file in your question?

Comment: I should have done that in the first place, I apologize. 
Thank you for the assistance and explanations.